# Why are Spring libraries including same parent packages made seperate?

Tags: java, spring, java-package

I've just noticed two different libraries sharing paths.
Example is as follows.
[image]
There are two seperate packages - `spring-boot-actuator`, `spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure`.

[image]

Packages included in these libraries share the same parent package or package path.
I can't imagine the things under the hood. Wouldn't this lead to linking errors?

Comment: Not clear what you are asking for. Package x.y.z is NOT the same as x.y.z.p ... so the fact that x.y.z has classes in one library, and x.y.z.p has classes in another one should really be not a problem. Also note: it for isn't ideal, but there isn't necessarily a problem when two different projects/library use the same x.y.z package. It only becomes complicted when you have two different classes BOTh named x.y.z.A ... then things become messy.

Comment: You don't seem surprised that both start with `org.springframework` though. Why would this be different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Package `a.b.c` is different from `a.b.c.d`, there is **no hierarchical relationship** between any two packages in Java, as we may assume.

Comment: *"there is no hierarchical relationship between any two packages in Java"* uhm... I'd take issue with this statement as written. Can you please clarify what you mean?

Comment: A parent child relationship nor dependency doesn't exist between packages, that could interfere with Class loading , but from Software design perspective hierarchies are needed for ease of development.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca As far as Java is concerned, package "x.y.z" is not contained in package "x.y". The fact that on the filesystem there might be a hierarchical relation does not translate to a hierarchical relation in Java itself. The naming structure is hierarchical (JLS 17 chapter 7), but packages themself are not.

Comment: Specifically, [JLS 17 section 7.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.1) says: _"The hierarchical naming structure for packages is intended to be convenient for organizing related packages in a conventional manner, but has no significance in itself other than the prohibition against a package having a subpackage with the same simple name as a top level class or interface (§7.6) declared in that package. "_

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Explained it well.